# Wordpress Post in Modal - Facebook Comments not showing

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, facebook, modal-dialog

I have created a wordpress site for a client and the Post open in a bootstrap modal. The problem I am experiencing is that I have a Facebook comments plugin installed and the FB Comments Plugin by Vivacity are not displaying but only the Comment title.

When I click on the button to close the modal, It looks the comments wants to show but the modal closes.

Is there a something I can do to force the facebook comments to display?

the link is [www.usaradio.live/blog](http://www.usaradio.live/blog)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have some errors in your console that maybe are related to your issue. Solve those errors before.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a Social Plugin in a dynamic way, so you have to call `FB.XFMBL.parse` as soon as the code of the Plugin is in the DOM: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse